# android custom buttons touch event

Tags: android

I have used 4 different colored custom shape buttons. I am trying to implement an ontouch listener by getting the pixel color as shown below

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    return isPixelTransparent(v, x, y) || v.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private boolean isPixelTransparent(View v, int x, int y) {
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
    try {
        color = bmp.getPixel(x, y);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // x or y exceed the bitmap's bounds.
        // Reverts the View's internal state from a previously set "pressed" state.
        v.setPressed(false);
    }
    return color == Color.TRANSPARENT;
}
```

However the rectangular area of the buttons overlap so the buttons underneath dont get pressed if pixel is transparent. Also please note all the buttons have large white text. I have done lots of searching but cannot figure out how to go about it, any help would be much appreciated please.

XML

```
    <za.co.####.####.DiamondShapeButton
        android:id="@+id/button_resources"
        style="@style/NavigationButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="@string/resources"
        custom:diamondColor="@color/red"/>

    <za.co.####.####.DiamondShapeButton
        android:id="@+id/button_practise"
        style="@style/NavigationButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="@string/practise"
        custom:diamondColor="@color/blue"/>

    <za.co.####.####.DiamondShapeButton
        android:id="@+id/button_tests_exams"
        style="@style/NavigationButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="@string/my_tests_exams"
        custom:diamondColor="@color/orange_light"/>

    <za.co.####.####.DiamondShapeButton
        android:id="@+id/button_track_studies"
        style="@style/NavigationButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="@string/track_studies"
        custom:diamondColor="@color/black"/>
</za.co.####.####.DiamondShapeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A View only knows about its own rectangular space, not that of the views that might be behind it.  So if a View has a transparent pixel, it will only know that its own pixel is transparent, not anything about the views that may be behind it.

If you want to have a view bypass some event handling, it will need to know about the views behind it and if they wish to handle the event instead.  You can't do this with pixel color of a single view - you will have to code this logic yourself based on the overall layout of the views.